# html display question

Tags: html, popup

I am doing a library website. Where user will click on the link of books and a pop up opens with the book.
I want the pop up page will be a single page in which the various books will uploaded but not using iframe.
How I will display the book content in this way? provided I have all the books in a html format.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want to do with the popup window. You want to display contents of a particular book? Or upload all books' information?

Comment: I want to display contents of a particular book in a html page provided I have the HTML version of all the books

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand what is being asked. Please try to make it clearer, possibly  use an image/wireframe to explain.

But, if you want all the each book's information to load into a single popup replacing the previous content, then you need to make use of the target attribute on the links that open the popup. Make all the target attributes the same and they'll all load the information into the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about what you want but I understood that you want something different to iframe to display your info... if I am right you should check this link http://prototype-window.xilinus.com